# aligned_alloc return assignment warning

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I am cleaning up warnings and found the following error:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast buf = aligned_alloc(ALIGN_VALUE,BUF_SZ);
```

This call is at the very top of the function, essentially:

```
char* buf;
buf = aligned_alloc(ALIGN_VALUE,BUF_SZ);
```

It is my understanding that aligned_alloc returns a void *. If cast the return from aligned_alloc to a (char *) I get:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-ast] buf = (char*)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_VALUE,BUF_SZ);
```

The only thing that seems to fix it is

```
buf = (char*)(uintptr_t)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_VALUE,BUF_SZ);
```

I have made sure that I am including stdlib.h to avoid implicit declarations referred to in another post. I assumed the cast to char pointer should have resolved this. I am not understanding why the cast to uintptr_t resolves it when void* and uintptr_t are equivalent as far as I understand.

The following is an example of the structure of the file

```
#include <syslog.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/hdreg.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h> // mmap
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void* ax_read_thread(void* arg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "read thread started\n");
    ax_priv* priv = (ax_priv*)arg;
    char* buf;
    uint32_t count = 0;

    size_t len, transferred = 0;
    buf = (char*)(uintptr_t)aligned_alloc(ALIGN_VALUE,BUF_SZ);

    if (buf == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Aligned alloc failed\n");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
    while(1){
    //do things
    }
}
```

Thank you for all of the help. I see now that the warning is a result of not indicating the proper version when invoking the compiler.

Comment: You forgot to declare `aligned_alloc`.

Comment: aligned_alloc is declared in stdlib.h which is included at the top of the file

Comment: Are you compiling with C or C++

Comment: I am compiling with c using gcc

Comment: It certainly looks like the function declaration of `aligned_alloc()` is missed - somehow.  Create a minimal example code showing the includes used and a `main()`.

Comment: `uintptr_t` and `void *` are not equivalent.  `uintptr_t` is an optional integer type. `void *` is a required pointer type.

Comment: Perhaps you are compiling with an older C version (or in C89 mode) which lacks `aligned_alloc()`?

Comment: Are you compiling with C11?

Comment: I am currently looking through the makefiles generated with autoconf to determine this

Comment: My glibc documentation (v 2.17) says that the feature test macro `_ISOC11_SOURCE` needs to be defined in order for `aligned_alloc()` to be declared (by `stdlib.h`).

Comment: I am seeing that now too. I am not familiar with doing something like this. Is there documentation or only source for what _ISOC11_SOURCE is for. Ok this link is helpful: [link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html)

Comment: `_ISOC11_SOURCE` is a feature test macro.  Is purpose is to influence which features are provided by the standard headers.  Define it (e.g. to 1) either via the compiler command line or in your source, before including any headers.  That will enable all features that are conditional on the macro.

Comment: Any recommendations for an aligned allocation of memory that doesn't require me to change the version I am compiling with. I am not familiar with specifying the version, risks?

Comment: no, you probably shouldn't declare `_ISOC11_SOURCE_` manually. Instead pass `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11` as argument to your compiler. Modern gcc have something like that as a default. You should look into updating it.Also, never cast away problems. They don't go away, you just only don't see them anymore.

Comment: How does this code even function if I am implicitly declaring a function?

Comment: How does the code function?  In general, when a prototype for a function is not available, then the returned type and each of the parameter types are assumed (by the compiler) to be `int`

Comment: That, and the C linker doesn't care or know about signatures (only names) - as long as it can find the requested symbol name at link time, it'll link it.

Comment: The function isn't available: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/C11Status.

Comment: @2501, experimentation shows that the function *is* available in glibc 2.17.

Answer (score 3):

This answer largely summarizes the observations and suggestions from the comments thread, including mine and many others', and wraps them in a bit of expository prose.

In the first place, the problem arises because when you build your program with your present toolchain, in its current form, the `aligned_alloc()` function is not explicitly declared.  In the absence of a declaration, the compiler is *inferring* its signature: it guesses that the function returns `int`, and that its parameter types are those obtained via the default argument promotions applied to the types of the actual arguments.  The compiler then warns you that those inferences -- especially the return type -- seem inconsistent with how you're actually using the function.

The solution, supposing that the function is available in your C library at all, is to ensure that a correct prototype is provided.  You *could* insert the prototype manually, but you shouldn't.  Since it's a standard library function, you should get its declaration from the appropriate header, which for this function is `stdlib.h`.

HOWEVER, this particular function is new in C11, and evidently you're using a version of GCC that defaults to compiling for an earlier standard.  Glibc supports that in part by protecting functions that are new in C11 with a [feature-test macro](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html), `_ISOC11_SOURCE`.  This is for your protection: in the event that you're building code written for an earlier standard, and that code happens to provide is own function with the same name as one of C11's new functions, the feature-test system prevents you from suffering a name collision.

If you are indeed writing for C11, as seems to be the case, and if your version of gcc has an option to support C11 (i.e. `-std=c11` and/or `-std=gnu11`), then compiling with that option enabled is your best alternative.  If you happen to have a version of Glibc that provides `aligned_alloc()` but not a version of the compiler that supports a C11 mode, then you have the alternative of manually ensuring that the needed feature test macro is defined to the compiler before any of the standard headers are included.  You can do that via a `#define` at the top of your source file, or via a command-line option to the compiler (e.g. `-D_ISOC11_SOURCE=1`).

Glibc *does* have `aligned_alloc()` from at least version 2.17 (but I think from as early as 2.16).  GCC *does* have a C11 mode since at least version 4.8.  If your versions of these components are at least that recent, then it should be sufficient to add the option `-std=c11` (to omit GNU extensions) or `-std=gnu11` (to support GNU extensions) to your compilation command:

```
gcc -std=c11 my_program.c
```

Comment: Is the inferred signature ultimately being used to call the aligned_alloc included in the stdlib.h?

Comment: @neostar63, I'm not sure I understand.  When C is forced to infer a function signature, it is because it needs the signature to generate code for a function call.  The inference would be pointless if the inferred signature were not going to be used.  In the (likely) event that the inferred signature is incorrect for the function named by the given identifier, undefined behavior results.  At no time, however, is either the inferred signature or the function itself in any header file.

Comment: Note also that C does not have function overloading.  It does not match functions to calls by *signature*; it matches them by *name* only.